# Como fazer um select levando em consideração se o registro existe, se não existir retornar null ou vazio

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Possuo um código que em retorna as atividades que foram concluídas dentro de um período de 12 meses.

```
SELECT   
  empresas,
  tipo_atividade,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_1,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_2,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_3,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_4,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_5,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_6,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_7,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_8,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_9,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_10,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_11,
  CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_12
FROM 
  tbl_atividades
WHERE 
  YEAR(dt_fim) = '2018'
GROUP BY 
  empresas, tipo_atividade;
```

Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entretanto existe uma falha neste código, o caso é se eu cadastrei uma empresa e informei que as atividades começarão apartir de julho por exemplo, de janeiro a junho não deveria aparecer como pendente, deveria aparecer como Null ou Vazio.

A minha dúvida é seguinte como eu posso informar na query para verificar se existe alguma atividade naquela data e se se nao tiver retornar null ou vazio.

Comment: Você não poderia trocar o "PENDENTE" então por "NULL", neste caso?

Comment: TENTE CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN dt_vencimento IS NULL THEN NULL
                    ELSE (CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 1 THEN 1 
                               ELSE 0 END))) > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_1,

Comment: @Motta - Aparentemente tem algum erro nesta query não rodou.

Comment: CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN dt_vencimento IS NULL 
        THEN NULL
  ELSE (CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 1 
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END)) 
      > 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'PENDENTE' END AS MES_1,

Comment: a ideia basica e se for nulo gerar um null pois null não soma

Comment: A ideia é boa , porém não deu resultado, o que ficou mais próximo disso foi 

CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) > 0 THEN STATUS ELSE NULL END AS MES_1

Comment: O que deu errado ?

Answer (score 1):

Para ser `null` você não retorna o `else` ou retorna `null`.

Da mesma forma, na soma, não precisa retornar 0.

```
SELECT   
  empresas,
  tipo_atividade,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 1 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_1,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 2 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_2,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 3 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_3,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 4 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_4,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 5 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_5,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 6 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_6,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 7 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_7,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 8 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_8,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 9 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_9,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 10 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_10,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 11 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_11,
  (CASE WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(dt_vencimento) = 12 THEN 1 END)) > 0 THEN 'OK' END) AS MES_12
FROM 
  tbl_atividades
WHERE 
  YEAR(dt_fim) = '2018'
GROUP BY 
  empresas, tipo_atividade;
```